# MySQL query for reassigning tags in pictures and avoiding duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following structure in MySQL, table 'images_tags':

```
id | image_id | tag_id
----------------------
1  |  243     | 52
2  |  94      | 52
3  |  56      | 52
4  |  56      | 53
5  |  56      | 54
```

Table 'tags':

```
id  | tag     
---------------
52  |  fashion 
53  |  cars  
54  |  sports  
55  |  bikes
```

I'm building a function in my CMS to delete a tag, for that I need to reassign all the pictures containing that tag to a another tag. The problem is the picture can already have assigned the new tag and I want to avoid possible duplicated records.

I couldnt find the right way to do it straight in SQL so I tried in PHP as follows:

```
$result=mysql_query("select image_id from images_tags where tag_id='".$oldtag."'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $result2=mysql_query("select id from images_tags
    where image_id='".$row['image_id']."' and tag_id='".$newtag."'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($result2)==0){

        mysql_query("update images_tags set tag_id='".$newtag."'
        where image_id='".$row['image_id']."' and tag_id='".$newtag."'");

    }

}
```

As you can see, my code is very bad and non-efficient as I'm running queries inside iterations. Do you know a better way to do this? Preferably in just one SQL query. Thanks.

Comment: You should have a composite unique key on `image_id` and `tag_id`.

Comment: `$row['id']` should be `$row['image_id']`? And where does `$newtag` come from?

Comment: sorry typo when writing the question. fixed.

Comment: Is there a table listing the possible tag IDs?

Comment: Yes, edited the question and added the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I think of this problem, I think of it more easily as "insert the new image tags, if appropriate, then delete the old ones".

The following code takes this approach:

```
create unique index image_tags_unique on image_tags(image_id, tag_id);

insert into image_tags
    select image_id, <newtagid>
    from image_tags
    where tag_id = <oldtagid>
    on duplicate key ignore;

delete from image_tags
    where tag_id = <oldtagid>;
```

The first step creates a unique index on `image_tags`, so duplicates are not allowed in the table.

The second inserts the new records, ignoring any errors generated by duplicates.

The third deletes the old records.

To be honest, you can also do this with the `ignore` keyword on `update` instead of `insert` step.  However, `ignore` is very general, so -- in theory -- there could be another error being ignored incorrectly.  The `on duplicate key ignore` is much more specific about what is allowed.

Comment: Isn't the question about how to pick the `<newtagid>`?

Comment: @Barmar . . . I don't think so.  Here is a quote:  " The problem is the picture can already have assigned the new tag and I want to avoid possible duplicated records."

Comment: And in order to avoid duplicated records, he needs to pick a new tag that doesn't match one that's already there. Otherwise he'll lose the record entirely when he deletes the old tag.

Comment: @BarMar . . . We are definitely interpreting the question differently.  From all I can see, the OP already knows the new tag id.  The question is how to assign it, because some images might already have that particular tag.

Comment: But he said this code is very bad because he's running queries inside iterations. He has to keep trying different $newtagid until he finds one that works.

Comment: @Barmar Gordon is right, my problem is very simple: to find the most efficient way to update the tag of a picture avoiding duplicated records. My knowledge of SQL is very basic, that's why I did it in PHP, but I couldnt find a better way than having queries inside iterations.

Comment: @Gordon From your answer I was able to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will add new rows to `images_tags` that meet your criteria.

```
insert into images_tags (image_id, tag_id)
select image_id, tag_id
from (select i.image_id image_id, t.id tag_id
      from images_tags i
      join tags t
      where i.tag_id = $oldtag and t.id != $oldtag) crossp
left join images_tags existing
using (image_id, tag_id)
where existing.id is null
group by image_id
```

The `crossp` subquery creates a full cross-product between all the image_ids that currently have the old tag, and all the tags other than the old tag. Then we do a left join with the existing `images_tags`, and use the `null` check to filter out all the pairs that already exist. This generates a list of `image_id` and `tag_id` pairs that do not match anything in the database. Finally we group by `image_id` so we just add one new row per image.

After you do this, you can delete the rows with `tag_id = $oldtag`.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a473/1)

The only problem with this is that it changes the IDs of the `images_tags` rows. There may be a way to do it all in one step with an `UPDATE` query, which wouldn't have that problem, but I'm not sure how to turn my query into that.